# cocos2d-x how to read plist into an array

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, plist, cocos2d-x

i want to read a plist using cocos2d-x (c++)
here is my plist:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>x</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>y</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>x</key>
        <integer>140</integer>
        <key>y</key>
        <integer>12</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>x</key>
        <integer>120</integer>
        <key>y</key>
        <integer>280</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>x</key>
        <integer>40</integer>
        <key>y</key>
        <integer>364</integer>
    </dict>
<array>
```

it's basically an array of dictionary that consist of (x, y) coordinates. 
my original code for reading is:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"w%i", world] ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray* points = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

but Now i need to translate it into cocos2d-x in c++. i've googled some article but they are all about reading plist into dictionary. i need an array.

EDIT:::

Now i've changed my plist format:

```
<dict>
    <key>11x</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>11y</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>12x</key>
    <integer>140</integer>
    <key>12y</key>
    <integer>12</integer>
<dict>
```

what should i do??? I still get the same error:

```
CCDictionary<std::string, CCObject*>* dict = CCFileUtils::dictionaryWithContentsOfFile(plistPath);
int x = (int)dict->objectForKey("11x");
int y = (int)dict->objectForKey("11y");
```

won't work. 
Please try it out first. see if you can read a int from the sample plist

Comment: I don't think coco2d-x support reading plist..but it support reading xml. So you can parse xml and get values

Comment: how? i think it supports plist and convert to a dictionary. (use FileUtil something)

Comment: aren't plist itself in xml format?

Comment: Yes plist is xml that's why I said to parse it. And I don't know about FileUtil. if i really works then post it as answer I will +1 it.

Comment: +1 your four answer for above info.

Comment: you need to try ccmutable array

Comment: check Edit 2 in my answer you can try it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the follwing line of code

```
//const char *pszPath = CCFileUtils::fullPathFromRelativePath(plistName);
//consider that file is in resource bundle..
// CCDictionary<std::string, CCObject*> *plistDictionary=CCFileUtils::dictionaryWithContentsOfFile("testplist.plist");
// CCArray *testitems = (CCArray*)plistDictionary->objectForKey("root");
```

**EDIT**

or you can try this too...

```
 CCDictionary<std::string, CCObject*> *plistDictionary = CCFileUtils::dictionaryWithContentsOfFile("testplist.plist");
 CCMutableArray<CCObject*> *testitems = (CCMutableArray<CCObject*>*)plistDictionary->objectForKey("root");
 CCLog("COUNT: %d", testitems->count());
```

**EDIT-2**

Try Following code in case of root is Dictionary

```
   var1 = atoi(valueForKey("blendFuncSource", dictionary));
    var2 = atoi(valueForKey("blendFuncDestination", dictionary));
```

Look Inside `CCParticleSystem.cpp` class you might get batter idea.
check `bool CCParticleSystem::initWithDictionary(CCDictionary<std::string, CCObject*> *dictionary)` inside `CCParticleSystem.cpp` class

Regards,
Nikhil

Comment: then how can i get each value (int)?

Comment: CCDictionary<std::string, int> point = testitems->objectAtIndex(index);
but error

Comment: each entry of the array is a dictionary

Comment: no viable conversion from cocos2d::ccobject to ccmutabledictionary<std::string, int>

Comment: CCDictionary<string, CCObject> miniDict = testitems->objectAtIndex(index); try something like that

Comment: CCDictionary<std::string, CCObject*> *plistDictionary=CCFileUtils::dictionaryWithContentsOfFile(plistStr.str().c_str());
    CCMutableArray<CCObject*> *points = (CCMutableArray<CCObject*>*)plistDictionary->objectForKey("root");
    int index = (level - 1) * num_images_in_level * 5 + (image - 1) * 5 + spot - 1;
    CCObject* pointObj = points->getObjectAtIndex(index);
    CCDictionary<std::string, int>* point = (CCDictionary<std::string, int>*) pointObj;

Comment: CCDictionary<std::string, CCObject*> *plistDictionary=CCFileUtils::dictionaryWithContentsOfFile(plistStr.str().c_str());
    CCArray *points = (CCArray*)plistDictionary->objectForKey("root");
    int count = points->count();

Comment: when i access count = points->count(), error message: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: you must try                                         CDictionary<std::string, CCObject*> *plistDictionary = CCFileUtils::dictionaryWithContentsOfFile("testplist.plist");
 CCMutableArray<CCObject*> *testitems = (CCMutableArray<CCObject*>*)plistDictionary->objectForKey("root");
 CCLog("COUNT: %d", testitems->count());

Comment: not working either. i even tried CCFileUtil::fullPathFromRelativePath

Comment: Hi, The CCParticle way works. but still no idea what's going on. could you dive into the code and make a conclusion on parsing plist files? since ppl might be using plists with different format. anyway this solved my problem. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

See here is the [link for reading a dictionary from file](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/embedded/cocos2d-x/d0/ddc/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_file_utils.html). 
To read array I couldn't find any thing so what you can do is change your plist to

```
<dict> <key>root</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
        <key>x</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>y</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>x</key>
        <integer>140</integer>
        <key>y</key>
        <integer>12</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>x</key>
        <integer>120</integer>
        <key>y</key>
        <integer>280</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>x</key>
        <integer>40</integer>
        <key>y</key>
        <integer>364</integer>
    </dict>
  <array>
</dict>
```

Then

```
CCDictionary<std::string, CCObject*> *dict = CCFileUtils::dictionaryWithContentsOfFile("yourFile.plist");
CCArray *testitems = (CCArray*)dict->objectForKey("root");
```

Thanks to [OMGPOP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/767653/omgpop).

Comment: but how can i get the value (int) from the array? when i use objectatindex, it returns an ccobject

Comment: hi, not working again, out of index even if i set the index to be within bound.

Comment: it seems the "root" does not exist. the objectForKey("root") returns NULL

Comment: if you can check I have edited the plist.. so you have to add this key as in my answer

Comment: yeah i noted that, but still that same problem. could you have a try? like reading a value x from sample plist?

Comment: Sorry I can't do anything apart this... if you get the solution do share it.. thanks

Comment: @NSMutableArrayRetain's solution is correct. please have a look. you probably need to have a look inside the ccparticlesystem.cpp file. cheers

Answer (score 2):

when you read in a dict and using `ObjectForKey("BLA")`, you can typecast it to a `CCString*` like this :

```
    CCString* tmpStr = (CCString*)(yourDict->ObjectForKey("KEY"));
    int x = tmpStr->toInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
Array* items = Array::createWithContentsOfFile("name.plist");
```